# How can i move file/folder of Nuxeo to Trash with REST API

Tags: rest, nuxeo

From Nuxeo REST API Document, I can see the deleted file/folder in TRASH with this code

```
SELECT * FROM Document WHERE ecm:mixinType != 'HiddenInNavigation' 
AND ecm:currentLifeCycleState = 'deleted' AND ecm:isProxy = 0 AND ecm:isCheckedInVersion = 0
```

But how can I update the Document with `ecm:currentLifeCycleState` to move Document to TRASH?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code I used to move a document to trash.

```
  public boolean deleteDocument(Session session, String documentId) throws Exception {
    try {
      Document document = getDocumentById(session, documentId);
      // When delete a document, only move it to Trash
      session.newRequest("Document.SetLifeCycle")
          .setInput(document).set("value", "delete").execute();
      return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

And the following code would delete the document permanently.

```
  public static boolean deleteDocument(Session session, String documentId) throws Exception {
    try {
      Document document = getDocumentById(session, documentId);

      // Delete the document permanently
      session.newRequest("Document.Delete").setInput(document).execute();
      return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

One way is to find the documents in trash first via a NXQL, like:

```
SELECT * FROM Document WHERE ecm:currentLifeCycleState = 'deleted'
```

And then delete them permanently via the method above. There is also a post mentioning this: http://answers.nuxeo.com/questions/1830/actioncommand-to-permanently-delete-all-document-in-trash

Utility method: fetch a document by documentId:

```
  public static Document getDocumentById(Session session, String documentId) throws Exception {
    try {
      return (Document) session.newRequest("Document.Fetch").set("value", documentId)
          .setHeader(Constants.HEADER_NX_SCHEMAS, "*").execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Failed to fetch document: " + e.getMessage(), e);
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's save my day. For more information, how can i delete all file/folder in the trash?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you have any ideas about delete 100 file? Should we call above method 100 times? Did Nuxeo support the API to delete multiple file, that mean we have to send the Array of 100 document ID and call "Document.Delete" ?

Comment: No I haven't seen a better way to empty the trash in Nuxeo. Yes, may need call that operation 100 times. It should be fast for 100 documents. If for event more documents, e.g. 10k (rarely) just need to write a background program to do it in a loop, with some pause if needed.

Comment: Document.SetLifeCycle: Inputs: document, documents. Do you have any idea with documents?

Comment: Ah, I see. You may get a Documents object when retrieving documents via NXQL. Perhaps you can try setInput(documents). I haven't tried it before, but it may work. I think the Nuxeo server operation will also loop through the documents.

Comment: Now, I have the String documentId, how can I create the Documents? I have tried but i failed, do you have any ideas to create it?

Comment: You have the documentId, then you can fetch the document and then get a Document object. I added the utility method in the answer so that we have a good code format.

Comment: I already know about how to create Document object, but I ask about Documents object. I tried to setInput with Documents and have this problems: {"entity-type":"exception","code":"org.nuxeo.ecm.automation.TraceException","status":500,"message":"Failed to invoke operation: Document.Delete"}

Comment: Just had a look at the source code of Document.Delete operation. Looks like it only accepts a single document each time. https://github.com/nuxeo/nuxeo-features/blob/master/nuxeo-automation/nuxeo-automation-core/src/main/java/org/nuxeo/ecm/automation/core/operations/document/DeleteDocument.java

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [Document.SetLifeCycle](http://explorer.nuxeo.org/nuxeo/site/distribution/current/viewOperation/Document.SetLifeCycle) operation to follow the `delete` transition.